# How to setup a run configuration for Ktor in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ktor

I try to add a run configuration in **IntelliJ IDEA** for my **Ktor** app using [their manual](https://ktor.io/docs/running.html#running-the-application-from-inside-the-ide) but it doesn't work:

[image: Screenshot]

And that's true, `io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain` is really not in my module. However, how to run it via **IntelliJ IDEA**? I added a configuration for **Gradle** but it seems an ugly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding `main` function with the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
```

and running it via [Kotlin run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-kotlin.html).